# Selenium(PYTHON) Syntax conundrum

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

So this is more of a conceptual question, but in any specific portion of a program, there are parents and children of objects. In my case I'm referencing the class/IDs and what not of HTML sources. Lets say I have 3 class names, each class as a subclass of the other:

```
class1= driver.find_element_by_class_name('parent_class')

class2 = class1.find_element_by_class_name('child_class')

class3 = class2.find_element_by_class_name('child_child_class')
```

I understand you can specify locating an element just by `find_element_by_class_name`, but in the case above, is there a way to print the text of `class2` written in the format of maybe

`print(class1.class2.class3)` type of format, where you are listing all the variables so you know exactly what your specifying. When there are multiple classes with the same name, you have to sometimes specify by index.

Comment: What does this have to do with syntax? Are you getting a `SyntaxError` somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Please read [ask]. Ideally, we'd like a [mcve] here.

Comment: no, its more about trying to understand if there is a way in which i can put all the class names in one line, where when reading it from left to right, it is the order of a class that holds a class that holds a class.....etc hence the idea of me writing out class1.class2.class3 where class 3 is inside class2 and class2 is inside class1, how would i format that where im not defining each individual class

Comment: Can you show the example of html that represents your idea and what should get queried and what should not?

Comment: You'd want to [Locating Elements by CSS Selectors](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors)

Comment: just look at the above example of class variables defined, what if i wanted to print the text inside class3, it would be print print(class3.text).... but what if i wanted to make sure that im including all the class names due to the fact that when class names share the same name, index comes into play, how can i write all the class names out when im making that print statement, because say class1 is the only class with its unique name, then i wont have to specify for the rest of the classes, but more importantly, i wanna know how i can do that all in one line by writing out all the class names

Comment: E.g., `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".class1 > .class2 > .class3")`.

Comment: ok thats more of what i was looking for, but what about not having to define the classes as variables and just writing out the class names as is

Comment: is this how i would write it out if instead im using the name of the class? ('coinflip-list__item' > 'item__controls' > 'value__primary')

Comment: if im writing down the names of the class, not the variables

Comment: @ExoticLegend714 This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?